# Why is $\mathcal M(\mathcal C) \subset \sigma (\mathcal C)$?

Tags: measure-theory

There should be an error in my logical reasoning but I can't figure out.

Every metric space is a topological space. So it can be understood that: metric space $\subset$ topological space.

Every $\sigma$-algebra is a monotone class. The same spirit applies, it can be understood that: $\sigma$-algebra $\subset$ monotone class.

But if we define monotone class generated by $\mathcal C$ by $\mathcal M(\mathcal C):=\bigcap\limits_{\mathcal M \text{ monotone class, } \mathcal C \subset \mathcal M} \mathcal M$ and $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal C$ by $\sigma(\mathcal C):=\bigcap\limits_{\mathcal T \sigma\text{-algebra, } \mathcal C \subset \mathcal T} \mathcal T$. Why is $\mathcal M(\mathcal C) \subset \sigma (\mathcal C)$?

Comment: Because $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C})$ is the smallest monotone class containing $\mathcal{C}$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is another monotone class containing $\mathcal{C}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is all correct.

1. The "something" generated by $\mathcal C$ is the SMALLEST "something" containing $\mathcal C$.
2. If $A \subset B$, then $\inf A \geq \inf B$. Apply similar spirit for the set of sets.